# What procedure was Alice going to take in Once Upon A Time In Wonderland?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

In Once Upon A Time in Wonderland, Alice wanted to forget about Cyrus by undergoing a special procedure. But what was it? Was it ever revealed?

Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was under the impression that the procedure in question was a [lobotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobotomy#Transorbital_lobotomy), though perhaps that isn't clear if you aren't already familiar with it. Assuming she'd survived the procedure I'm not sure if it would have taken away her memories of Cyrus anyway, since they were real rather than - as everybody else believed - delusions.

From Wikipedia:

> Lobotomy (Greek: λοβός – lobos: "lobe (of brain)"; τομή – tomē: "cut/slice") is a neurosurgical procedure, a form of psychosurgery, also known as a leukotomy or leucotomy (from the Greek λευκός – leukos: "clear/white" and tome). It consists of cutting or scraping away most of the connections to and from the prefrontal cortex, the anterior part of the frontal lobes of the brain.

Comment: It has not been stated in the episodes. But I think lobotomy is the right answer, too. The time where it happens is where lobotomy has been a wonder cure for everything (lobotomy has a terrifying history!) and even how they offer her this special procedure.

Comment: Before correcting himself to "make you forget", the first phrase he used was "take away your pain".  Frontal-lobe lobotomies can indeed do that.

Comment: Another contemporary procedure, electroshock therapy, could also work. The procedure reportedly randomly jumbles memories to some degree, sometimes making them no longer accessible and sometimes bringing up older memories that you'd lost the pointer to.